# What are my best options for powerful member management with many custom fields?

Tags: members, custom-fields, member-details

Working on a college site that will have many, many members (in the hundreds), only a fraction of which will actually be editors in the CMS. All members need to have access to their own information (so they can update with ease). Each member will have a ton of custom fields, too, including specialty fields like Matrix and Playa (which, as I understand it, isn't allowed with the built-in member management).

What are my options here? Really appreciate any suggestions I can get.

Comment: This may be helpful in comparing the different 3rd party solutions: http://focuslabllc.com/blog/member-profile-add-ons-in-expressionengine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of member add-ons that substitute the native member module for channel entries.

They are:

- [Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/)
- [Profile:Edit](http://mightybigrobot.com/products/detail/profile-edit)
- [Safecracker Registration](https://objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration)

Since members are handled as regular channel entries, you are free to use any custom fieldtype.

Also, since they are channel entries, you can use [Safecracker](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html) to allow the users to edit their own profiles/entries.

As Erik mentioned, Focus Lab wrote up [a comparison of the big 3 membership addons](http://focuslabllc.com/blog/member-profile-add-ons-in-expressionengine) mentioned above.

Comment: While Profile:Edit is a fairly solid add-on, the support over at Barrett-Newton/MightyBigRobot has been quite abysmal lately. I'd recommend going with the other options if you don't want to get stuck in support limbo halfway through your project.

Comment: Might want to double check your link to the Focus Lab article. :)

Comment: I have been using Profile:edit on several builds, support has been very good. One can book a meeting on Skype or telephone and discuss problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think almost any of the 'member data' in channels add-ons will work for you. Which one would be best, would require more information on what you hope to do with members, besides let them create detailed profiles.

All the 'member data' in channels add-ons, still use EE's Membership Module to manage permissions, and it can easily handle hundreds of records. We've got a couple of clients with more than 45,000 members, and the Membership Module handles it fine. One ONLY uses the Membership Module, the other uses [Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/).

The membership management field is pretty long, just take a look at [Devot-ee](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=member&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2), but if you want to start exploring, I'd look at these items: [Safecracker Registration](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/safecracker-registration), [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor), and [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit).

They offer similar flexibility in terms of being able to handle anything you can throw at channel data, but depending on what else you want to accomplish one maybe better than the other for you.

Answer (score 0):

an option could be visitor, you can use matrix and playa (or other fieldtypes) there http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/

Comment: Welcome Hala. Please be more descriptive in considered in your answers. This answer reads like a tweet. :)